# Execute a shell command outside of a sandbox while in a sandbox

Tags: singularity-container

I'm using singularity to run python in an environnement deprived of python. I'm also running a mysql instance as explained by the IOWA state university (running an instance of mysql, and closing it when done).

For clarity, I'm using a bash script to open mysql, then do what i have to do (a python script) and close mysql, and it works fine. But Python's only way to stop if an error occured is sys.exit([value]) and this not only stops the python script, but also the bash script that ran it. This makes it impossible for me to manage the errors and close the instance of mysql if the python script exits.

My question is : Is there a way for me to execute a 'singularity instance stop mysql' while being in the python sandbox. Something to tell singularity "hey, this command here must be used on the host !" ?

I keep searching but can't find anything.

I only tried to execute it with subprocess like any other command, but it returned an error message because I don't have this instance inside the python sandbox. I don't even have singularity in this sandbox.

For any clarifications, just ask me, I'm trying to be clear but I'm pretty sure it's not very clear.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it would be a big security issue if a process could be initiated from inside a container (docker or singularity) but run in the host OS's namespace.

If the bash script is exiting on the python failure, it sounds like you're using `set -e` or `#!/bin/bash -e`. This causes the script to abort if any command returns non-zero. It's commonly recommended for safer processing, but can cause problems like this at times. To bypass that for the python step you can modify your script:

```sh
# start mysql, do some stuff

set +x # disable abort on non-zero return
python my_script.py
set -x # re-enable abort on non-zero

# shut down mysql, do other stuff
```